Name of a (classical?) piece I recorded, played by a small instrument group. (audio gets better after a few seconds)
I've been looking for this piece since at least October 2023 but had no luck so far.
I cannot find how to embed videos on this side, so here is a link to me asking the same question with video on Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/findthatsong/comments/1es0xdr/name_of_a_classical_piece_i_recorded_played_by_a/
Here is some additional info that may help:

The small instrument group played in front of the entrance of a canteen at Leipzig University in Germany (but I don't think the piece has to be a German one necessarily).
I recorded this audio from a seperate room. I basicaly recorded two segments of the song:

the first is about 12 seconds long
followed by 2 seconds by silence that I added to clearly seperate both segments
the second segment is about 15 seconds long



Sorry if the audio quality is not the best, but it should pick up a few seconds into the video.
I would appreciate any help, thanks in advance!

Hi Lisa, identification requests are unfortunately not on-topic on this site. I hope Reddit can help you out!
